# Python: Parse large json file

Tags: python, json

I have a large json file. Its log data and I have compressed it to bz2 format (myfile.json.bz2). Size of the bz2 file is 90MB. I searched to find a good solution or a blog post that explain parsing compressed bz2 json file efficiently but was not able to find any.

Since the file is large doing something like is impossible.

```
with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

what is the best approach?

After some digging around I found there is a python package to read bz2

```
input_file = bz2.BZ2File(filename, 'r')
```

Comment: You want an incremental json parser, e.g. see this answer: [(link)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10715686/866915) Another possibility is this: [(link)](https://github.com/nigelsmall/jsonstream)

Comment: since `BZ2File` has a `read` method that returns an arbitrary number of bytes, I would probably consider trying to read the json as a stream, with something like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/

Answer (score 2):

If someone is looking for a way to parse wikidata json dump compressed in bz2 here is a snippet of code:

```
import bz2
import json

f = bz2.BZ2File("latest-all.json.bz2", "r")
next(f)  # skip the first line
for line in f:
    print(json.loads(line[:-2]))
```

Comment: And the magic -2 stands for white endline character `\n\r`?

Comment: The `-2` stands for comma `,` and the end of the line. The fatest performance wise, would be to parse with a json streaming parser.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any other suggestions or existing code I would recommend opening a stream and manually parsing the braces and brackets (`{` and `[` respectively) until you have a complete object `{ ... }` and run deserialization on that. This will allow you to chunk the JSON while leveraging existing JSON libraries.

This is not a solution I would typically recommend but it's the quickest and most reliable solution I can think of if existing libraries don't suit your needs.

Comment: It would be easier and safer to use an incremental JSON parser like http://pykler.github.io/yajl-py/, rather than figuring it out yourself.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of that library.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have compressed the file itself, once you load it into python  using Python's `json` package, you end up loading the entire thing into memory. Due to how Python works, if say the file is 100MB, you typically end up using a fair bit more. I recently observed that loading a 324MB JSON used up 1.5GB of memory.

Now, if the issue is storage, then compression is the way to go, however, if you're needing to run it into a program you'd probably want to think about how to read the JSON one object at a time as supposed to load the entire thing into memory.

What @amirouche has suggested should work if you're happy to do it "by hand" for go it. For something already available, https://pypi.org/project/json-lineage/ might be a possible solution. Disclaimer, I did write the code for this.

I'm sure there are other tools out there that do the same - read JSON one object at a time.

if you do end up using json-lineage, here is a small guide that could do the trick for you:

```py
from json_lineage import load

jsonl_iter = load("path/to/file.json")


for obj in jsonl_iter:
    do_something(obj)
```

.

Comment: [/help/promotion](/help/promotion) you need to very clearly and very explicitly state any affiliation you have with what you're promoting.