# How can I read json file only partially in python?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a json file.
When this json file is loaded to dataframe,
columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
But 'C' and 'D' columns are only useful.
So, I want to load only 'C' and 'D' columns from json file.
What should I do?

```
import pandas as pd
A = pd.read_json('./data/my_json.json')
A.drop(['A', 'B', 'E', 'F'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This code is a waste of memory.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. It has to read the entire thing to parse the columns.

Comment: Ah, sad. Thank you.

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715628/opening-a-large-json-file-in-python ; or this: https://pypi.org/project/ijson/ .

Comment: Good information, Thank you.