# Filter complex JSON array with Python

Tags: python, json

I have a [**Large Json Data**](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pgSZ2r9vWW/). It contains thousands of entries for category data.

I want to filter out categories that have no subcategories nested inside. The absence of a subcategory means it's an empty list.

**For example:** https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cHg8vnQyZm/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening A large JSON file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715628/opening-a-large-json-file-in-python)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, that's not the answer I'm looking for. I can open the json file.

Comment: OK. So, is there any problem at all with the file being large or not? You have mentioned it so many times (large, big, thousands, such a large).

Comment: Sorry, I might not have expressed myself correctly. I said so because there are so many categories. Yes. Exactly what I want is to filter.

Comment: Please edit the code of your attempt to filter this data into your question as a [mre]. Also change the title as neither parsing not largeness are the issue, it is filtering that you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to StackOverflow. I'm sorry if I bothered you. I fixed the problem, I'll leave the codes below. Thank you everyone, I wish you healthy days.

```
import ijson

def parser(filename):
  with open(filename, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as json:
    parser = ijson.parse(json)
    prefixes = []
    for prefix, event, value in parser:
      if prefix.endswith(".subCategories") and not value:
        if prefix not in prefixes:
          prefixes.append(prefix)

    nullCategories = []
    for rank in range(len(prefixes)):
      json.seek(0)
      for nullCategory in ijson.items(json, prefixes[rank]):
        nullCategories.append(nullCategory)

    return nullCategories


if __name__ == "__main__":
  lists = [category for category in parser("data.json") if category]

  for x in lists:
    print(x[0]["name"])
```

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, I forgot to say something. My goal is not just to get subcategories with empty content. My main goal is to get the names of subcategories with empty content.

With **ijson** I managed to get all subcategories with empty content:

```
import ijson


def load_json(filename):
  with open(filename, "rb") as json:
    parser = ijson.parse(json)
    prefixes = []
    for prefix, event, value in parser:
      if prefix.endswith(".subCategories") and not value:
        prefixes.append(prefix)

    for x in prefixes:
      print(x)

load_json("data.json")
```

But I couldn't find a way to get the names of these categories